# How to undo applications installed “as admin”?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, windows-installer

On Server 2016 installed an application by running setup 'as admin'. Now that the app is up and running, I'm really wishing I hadn't installed it as admin. Aside from uninstalling/reinstalling, is there an easy way to undo the "as admin" part?

Would copying all the files to a non-NTFS partition, deleting the original, and then copying the files back undo this?  Interested in knowing more about what all is affected when 'as admin' is invoked, and how to undo it.

Comment: Most applications must be installed with administrator rights, because they write to paths on the disk, where normal users can not write. However this does **not** mean that the application will run with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. When app is installed with admin priviliges, it goes under Program Files directory so all users can use it.

If you install (and the app suports it) with admin rights, it goes under user's %appdata% directory. The only way now is to reinstall.